# how to do pause after paragraph while textToSpeech

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, ssml

i have a text which is used for textToSpeech.
i want to do a **pause** in the text which is readed from the dragon mobile SDK for iPhone.
the text is without the SSML. only blanc text.

What kind of charactars can i use for pause? I know that after a " . " is a pause, i tried to do two . like ".   ." but doesnt work.

How can i do pause after ***paragraph*?**

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
//Do here a long pause from 3 seconds
Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found it. no way out to use SSML. and SSML is incredible :)
have to use the break tag in SSML, see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.3